# Why does my image not appear?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Hi I wonder why my image doesn't appear. I *think* it is stored both as a blobproperty and in the blobstore since it appears like a thumbnail on the list page. The address to the page where the image doesn't appear is http://www.koolbusiness.com/servead/4125209

And the thumbnail from the same image appears in the list http://www.koolbusiness.com/li

Some of my template code to display image is:

```
{% if ad.matched_images.get %} <table><tr>
        <td>

            <div class="ad_pict" id="display_image"><img src="{{url}}" alt="" onload="show_hidden_elements();return false;"></div>

       </td> <td>

{% ifequal len 1 %}
{% else %}
          {% for im in imv %}

            <div id="thumb0" class="ad_thumb ad_border_solid_black" onclick="showLargeImage('{{im}}');thumbnailBorder(this, 5 )">
                <table class="clean_table shadowed_thumb" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src="/_/img/thumb_left_top.gif"></td>
                            <td class="top_middle" align="left" valign="bottom"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="middle_left"></td>
                            <td><img src="{{im}}=s120" alt="">

</td>
                            <td class="single_middle_right" valign="top"><img src="/_/img/thumb_single_right_top.gif"></td>
                        </tr> 
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="single_bottom_center" valign="top"><img src="/_/img/thumb_single_left_bottom.gif"></td>
                            <td valign="top"><img src="/_/img/thumb_single_right_bottom.gif"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

            {% endfor %}

{% endifequal %}
```

Ans som eof my serverside python to load the template is:

```
class AdHandler(I18NHandler):
    def get(self, id):
        ad = Ad.get_by_id(long(id))
        if not ad:
            self.error(404)
            return
        image = ad.matched_images.get()
        url=''
        if image:
            if image.primary_image:
                url = images.get_serving_url(str(image.primary_image.key()))

        imv = []
        table=''
        for i in ad.matched_images:
            if i.primary_image:
              i1=images.get_serving_url(str(i.primary_image.key()))
              imv.append(i1)

        self.render_template("imageinfo.html", {'url':url,
        'imv':imv,'len':len(imv),
        'ad':ad,
        'image': image,
        'logout_url': users.create_logout_url('/'),
    })
```

If I use the old version of the page the image does appear so it's clear that I have it in the database, I've just written a bug and need to structure my migration from the blobproperty to the blobstore: http://www.koolbusiness.com/4125209

Since the image appears at the later url I know it's there and it's just a bug in my code somewhere that I can't reproduce that makes the image not appear. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would guess that one of these two if statements is evaluating to false:

```
    if image:
        if image.primary_image:
            url = images.get_serving_url(str(image.primary_image.key()))
```

If you were actually calling get_serving_url, you would either get a valid serving URL or an exception. Instead, url still has its starting value, a blank string.

Comment: Thanks! You're perfectly right. It was the image.primary_image that sometimes evaluates to false. I don't know why but at least now I managed a workaround adding a clause `else:`